# css3 and dreamweaver

Tags: css, dreamweaver

i have just downloaded dreamweaver cs5.5 and am trying to apply css3 to my page, however although my current css is working fine both in dreamweaver and other coders the new css3 is not being applied.
eg i am trying to apply border-radius, although it is showing up in my css list as i type it out (unlike microsoft expression 4, which is'nt although i believe it should), it is not being applied to the actual page. 
i have also tried using box-shadow, and linear-gradient, both unsuccessfully which made me believe that it is a css3 issue.
could it be something like setting up dreamweaver to accept css3, (ticking/unticking something in settings).

i am a beginner, any help would be appreciated and also i have looked it up before submitting q, but it seems not much info on css3 and especially css3 with dreamweaver.
thanks in advance

Comment: Which browser are you testing in?

Comment: IE9 doesn't support gradients without the use of [`filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to include properties for all browsers? also, can we see your css?
Cross compatible linear gradient needs to look like this:

```
linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(48,54,48) 0%, rgb(54,61,54) 100%); 
-o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(48,54,48) 0%, rgb(54,61,54) 100%); /*opera*/
-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(48,54,48) 0%, rgb(54,61,54) 100%);/*mozilla*/
    -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(48,54,48) 0%, rgb(54,61,54) 100%);/*chrome*/
-ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(48,54,48) 0%, rgb(54,61,54) 100%);/*IE*/
```

Comment: #box {
  border: 1px solid #696;
  padding: 60px 0;
  text-align: center; width: 200px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
  background: #EEFF99;
  background: linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
  font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif
  }

Comment: i tried ur methods using moz and webkit also didnt work, the prob is i cant view any implementations in dreamweaver in the first place let alone browser.

Comment: Probably is a Dreamweaver menu item in need of ticking, then.  My only other concern is that maybe dreamweaver isn't smart enough to recognize linear-gradient in its current context and needs to see the gradient explicitly under the background-image attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Please see what browser you are using Internet explorer 8 and below may not support the css3 newly introduced styles.check it in a browser like chrome. Also refer to the answer from @rfinz you can see how he does it for different browsers. You probably have to work along the same lines